# Clean way to derive Eq

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'd like to declare an AST as an instance of Eq but don't want to repeat the same steps for every constructor (2 expr are the same if all their sub-terms are the same). So first question is, is the GHC "deriving" sufficient? What does it do? If not, is there a clean way to avoid repetition? Maybe generic programming?

Comment: You can examine the (usually pretty readable but for uniquified naming) code that GHC produces for derived instances by compiling with `-ddump-deriv`. Check section 6.13.1 of the GHC Users Guide for a list of all of the intermediate forms you can get GHC to barf up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived instance of `Eq` returns `True` for two objects `x` and `y` if both of the below are true:

- `x` and `y` were produced by the same data constructor (and therefore also have fields of the same types)
- The respective fields of `x` and `y` are equal to each other (via their respecitve `Eq` instances)

For example, consider

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

The derived `Eq` instance looks like this:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) where
   Nothing == Nothing  = True
  (Just x) == (Just y) = x == y
         _ == _        = False
```

Answer (score 1):

GHC's deriving does exactly what you describe. Given a data type `data X = A ... | B ... | C ...` it declares two values equal when they have the same constructor and all of the arguments to the constructor are equal as well. This implies that there must be an `Eq` constraint on all of the arguments of every constructor. If they are concrete types then deriving will fail at compile time if an `Eq` instance cannot be found. If they are variables then the `Eq` constraint is passed up into the `instance` definition.